# Exact solution to the first order matrix differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, matrix-equations

I wonder whether the matrix differential equation
$$\dot x(t) + A(t) x(t)=0,$$
can be solved exactly. Here, $x(t)$ is a 4-component vector and $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Question: Does the above equation exactly solvable, for general $A(t)$?

If not, suppose further that $A(t)$ has the following form
$$A(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
0&c& e^{i\omega t}& 0 \\
c&0&0& e^{i\omega t} \\
e^{-i\omega t} & 0& 0& c \\
0& e^{-i\omega t}& c& 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Here, $c, \omega$ are constants. With these assumptions, does the above differential equation exactly solvable?

If the answer is again no, then I wonder the exact solvability of the following simplified differential equation:
$$\dot y(t) + B(t) y(t)=0,$$
where
$$B(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & e^{i\omega t} \\ e^{-i\omega t} & c \end{pmatrix}.$$
Again, $c,\omega$ are constants.

The above questions are motivated from physics. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $A(t)$, we have $[A(t),A(t')]\neq 0$ and also $[ \int^t dt'' A(t''), A(t)] \neq 0]$, so no nice simplification occurs. The general solution is given by $X(t)=\left( 1+\int^t dt' A(t')+ \int^t dt' A(t') \int^{t'}dt'' A(t'')+\dots \right) X(0)$, the so-called 'matrizant'. Perhaps some simplification within the iterated integrals occurs for your particular choice of $A$, but I'm unsure about that yet.